# Angular-nvd3 linechart with lines rendered outside chart

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using Krispos [angular-nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3) to render a line chart. For some reason the lines are rendered outside the chart or the dates are wrong. The x-axis is a time scale and the min and max values of the `xDomain` is set using datepicker.

When setting the `xDomain` the chart is rendered with the selected start and end dates as min and max values of the x axis. However, the lines are rendered outside the time interval due to the dataset has minimum date occuring before the selected start date. In this example the start date selected is *2015-08-08* and the end date *2015-11-08*:

[image: Image with lines rendered outside chart]

If I use `forceX` instead of `xDomain` to set the min and max values, the lines are rendered within the chart grid. But the in this case the min date of the dataset is before the selected start date, so the x axis starts on *2015-07-07* instead of *2015-08-08*. Illustrated below:

[image]

These are the basic chart options used. `xDomain` or `forceX` are set dynamically.

`$scope.chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                yDomain: [0,5],
                xDomain: [moment(data.startDate).valueOf(), moment(data.endDate).valueOf()],
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                interactiveLayer: {
                    showGuideLine: true
                },
                lines: {
                },

                xScale: d3.time.scale(),
                xAxis: {
                    showMaxMin: true,
                    rotateLabels: -45,
                    tickFormat: function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d));
                    }
                },
                height: 350,
                margin : {
                    bottom: 100
                }
            }
        };`

Do I need to use range in some way to get working properly, ie render the data within the selected start and end dates only.

Thankful for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this issue was to use the chart option `clamp()`, in this case:

```
xScale: d3.time.scale().clamp(true)
```

The date scale is set using `xDomain`:

```
xDomain: [moment(data.startDate).valueOf(), moment(data.endDate).valueOf()]
```

[image]